# How to fix Array error Undefined Offset in PHP

Tags: arrays, laravel

Concat the data that have same date but error on 3rd iteration. Concat the data that have same date but error on 3rd iteration.

```
 $summary = SummaryReport::with('accomplishments.employee')->with(['accomplishments' => function 
 ($query) use ($employee) {
        $query->where('emp_id', $employee->id);
        $query->orderBy('date', 'ASC');
 }])->find($id);

    $accomplishments = [];
    $date = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($summary->accomplishments); $i++) {
        if ($summary->accomplishments[$i]["date"] == $date) {
            $accomplishments[$i - 1]['accomplishment'] = $accomplishments[$i - 1]['accomplishment'] . ', ' . $summary->accomplishments[$i]['accomplishment'];
            continue;
        }
        array_push($accomplishments, $summary->accomplishments[$i]);
        $date = $summary->accomplishments[$i]['date'];
    }
```

Comment: It should throw error even on the `first` iteration due to the logic inside the for loop `i - 1`

Comment: Yes but in the first and second iteration it is okay but on the 3rd it gives me error

Comment: Can you just print the `accomplishments` and the `expected output` so I can help you with this

Comment: My data are too long in parsed, is it okay to screenshot in raw data?

Comment: Just show me an object of accomplishments and your expected output

Comment: "id": 141,
"emp_id": 1,
"goal_id": 70,
"date": "2020-07-25",
"accomplishment": "huihuihuigyugyugyu",
"no_of_hours": null,
"percentage_of_goal": 50,
"remarks": null,
"summary_report_id": 11,
"created_at": "2020-07-23T06:12:20.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-23T06:13:16.000000Z",
"employee": {
"id": 1,
"code": "1",
"first_name": "admin",
"middle_name": "",
"last_name": "",
"suffix": null,
"job_designation": "Admin",
"department": "Admin",
"department_head": "",
"status": 1,
"user_id": 1,

Comment: i returned the accomplishments and that is one of the result

Comment: You're overwriting the date at the end of each iteration if the date doesn't match. So the final array you'll have would not contain the elements with same date. Not that this answers your question, but it kinds of seem that you want to group the accomplishments according to the date.

Comment: And it would be great if you could explain what you want to do in the statement. From the query it seems like you want accomplishments associated with a given employer and associated with a given SummaryReport. But the query you've written would not get you this.

Comment: Yes i want to group by the date and concat there data.

Comment: Please share the models, shcema of the tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218734/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-asphyx1a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplishments of a particular employee from a particular SummaryReport, grouped by the date

After your query do the following

```
$acc_by_date = $summary->accomplishments->groupBy('date');

$result = [];
foreach($acc_by_date as $date => $accs){
   $result[$date] = [
       'accomplishments' => $accs->pluck('accomplishment')->reduce(
           function ($carry, $item) {
              return $carry . ", " .  $item;
       }),
       'remarks' => $accs->pluck('remarks')->reduce(
           function ($carry, $item) {
              return $carry . ", " .  $item;
       }),
       'remarks_as_array' => $accs->pluck('remarks') 
   ];
}
```